# MS Word: How do I align the over braces of this equation?

Tags: ms-office

How do I align the over braces of this equation in word, from this

[image]

into this

[image]

I would like all parenthesis the same height but I think this is asking for too much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

A1. Insert > Text Box > Draw a Text Box

[image]

A2. Drag text box
[image]

A3. Paste anything you want inside

A4. Position anywhere you want in the page

**OR**

B1. Build a table scheme like this:

[image]

B2. Place your elements
[image]

B3. Select all, right click, cell alignment > align center

[image]

B4. Goto to borders and shanding 
[image]

B5. Select "None"
[image]

B6. Enjoy
[image]

Comment: I'm glad to help!